# Using dispatch_after to do something relative to when something else finishes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Here is what I need to do:

Something like:

```
for int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
call method @selector(spin) with delay 0.1

//once this is done (e.g., in 0.3 seconds)

call method @selector(move) with delay 1 second.
```

What I need is to pile on events, and have other events start relative to when the previous one finishes.

So something like:

```
wait 100ms //total time = 100ms
spin
wait 100ms //total time = 200ms
spin
wait 100ms //total time = 300ms
spin
wait 1000ms //total time = 1300ms
move
```

Is something like this possible with dispatch_after? If so could someone give me an example? I cannot seem to find one for this case.

Note, none of this should cause the UI thread to wait / block.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`NSThread`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `sleepForTimeInterval` method. The following code will block the thread `sleepForTimeInterval` is running on.

```
dispatch_queue_t yourThread = dispatch_queue_create("com.xxx.queue", nil);

dispatch_async(yourThread, ^
{
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10.0];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {

    }); 
});
```

This should point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that you're trying to achive the goal in wrong way. When you deal with asynchronous process you should use blocks

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your request :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self performSelector:@selector(move:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] afterDelay:2];

}

-(void) move:(NSNumber *)i {
    int val = [i intValue] + 1;

//do what you need here

    if (val < 3) [self performSelector:@selector(move:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:val] afterDelay:2];

}
```

But Of course if you need to process a lot of data, use other thread instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_time_t timeNow = DISPATCH_TIME_NOW;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(timeNow, i*100), queue, ^(){
        [self spin];
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    });
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^(){
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1000), queue, ^(){
        [self move];
    });
});
```